# Eager Load in ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an ActiveJob with some parameters that have been serialized with GlobalID.

When performing the job, how can I eager load some associated models ?

```
class Foo
  has_one :bar
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
  field :some_field
end

class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(foo)
    # How can I eager load bar ?
    foo.bar.some_field # Hits the DB again without eager loading
  end
end
```

This is just a simple example but in my app I would need to eager_load several models, and smetimes I even have N+1 problems without it (on different examples, without eager loading)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this would cause an N+1 issue if `foo` and `bar` are singular items.

Otherwise, eager loading works in ActiveJob just like ActionControler, or anywhere else:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
  field :some_field

  def title
    "Title"
  end
end
```

You would eager load the `:bars` association like so:

```
foo = Foo.find(id).includes(:bars)

foo.find_each do |foo_item|
   # Process foo.bar.title without needing another query...
end
```

Also, if possible, you should pass primivies (e.g. `id` ) rather than a objects to your `perform` method. Active Job needs to serialize an object before inserting it in the queue, so sometimes its simpler and easier to fetch the object from the database via the `id` reference.

Comment: So basically the [globalID](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid) trick becomes useless if we need Eager Loading ?